# SSLException:Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Tags: scala, ssl, https, spray

I Have a Spray Scala project. I am doing HTTPS connection with Self Signed Certificate (.jks) to this project through REST call. I referred this link  [Configuration issue for Spray https server with self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853953/configuration-issue-for-spray-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate) to configure spray to https server. so when i run my project it reads `.jks` certificates but when i fire request it gives following error :

```
Aborting encrypted connection to /192.168.1.3:46346 due to [SSLException:Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. so when i configured spray to `HTTPS` it cant accept the `HTTP` requests it accepts only `HTTPS` requests.