# Akka TCP IO connect to SSL server

Tags: java, scala, ssl, tcp, akka

I'm trying to connect to a plain SSL socket according to http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/io-tcp.html and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/io-tcp.html. TCP connection is created just fine, but there's no TLS connection established. I've found (or at least I think so) how it's done on server side and in Akka HTTP and `Spray`, but I don't need HTTP, so it's of no use. There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797965/tcp-socket-with-ssl-on-scala-with-akka), which sounds exactly the same as mine, but it's two years old and the only answer suggests using `Spray`. Is such thing at all possible with Akka?

Comment: I'm finding references to TLS in the streams, but I can't find one for the basic TCP.